# Optimal use of a timing pulse

Tags: arduino, timing, attiny85

I have an indicator module that uses an ATTiny85 to switch an array of LEDs based on an RS-485 signal delivered by SoftwareSerial and a MAX485 IC. The indicator can be Off, On, or Flashing. All power and data signals are provided by a ribbon connector and as such many can be connected in parallel using intermediate connectors on the ribbon cable. There is a specific design requirement for the isolation of the 24V LED power and 5V MCU power hence why I've not just used a transistor or driven the MOSFET directly.

In addition to the 5V Power for the ATTiny and associated components, I have a timing pulse (on my schematic `F5V`) which is used to keep the pulsing in sync with other modules on the RS-485 bus, fed from the same place as the RS-485 signal.

My question focuses on the best way to integrate my timing signal. My current design is to use a two-channel optoisolator with the phototransistor side connected in parallel - effectively like an optical `or` gate. The system works by driving the respective IO pin low where it sinks the current passing through the optoisolator LED and resistor. One channel is for the steady `5V` power for the static ON signal, and the second is for `F5V` which is the Flashing ON signal. `F5V` acts like a regular 5V signal that is being switched on and off and so current only flows illuminating the optoisolator LED when `F5V` is in the High 5V state AND the IO pin is LOW.

I feel like there has to be a more efficient way of doing this, and I'd like to replace the two-channel optoisolator with a single channel optoisolator that handles both static and flashing states, but I don't know if:

- My current design is the more optimal design,
- Whether I should use some kind of `or` gate on the MCU side with the IO pins,
- If I should feed `F5V` into the ATTiny and have it factor in the timing signal to the switching if it is set to flash, meaning I'd only need one IO pin (and thus a single optoisolator) although I don't know if this would compromise the synchronisation by re-introducing the unpredictable clock differences between individual ATTiny ICs on each module (the reason behind the external signal),
- or something I haven't even thought of yet.

Put simply, is there a better way to switch the LED indicator on and off in flash mode, bearing in mind the timing signal and requirement for synchronisation of the indicators?

I should add that I am considering reversing the LEDs so that the IO pins *source* the current (i.e. IO HIGH = Opto LED ON) and have the `F5V` act as the current sink if that can affect the design.

**Schematic** (For the sake of keeping the schematic compact, I've omitted the MAX485 IC and replaced the array of 55 LEDs and 11 resistors with just one of each):
[image: Schematic]

**Key to Nets:**
`VIN` - 24V LED Power
`VGND` - 24V LED Ground
`5V` - MCU/Static 5V supply
`F5V` - Flashing 5V supply
`GND` - 5V Ground
`INDS` - **S**tatic IO Pin
`INDF` - **F**lashing IO Pin
`SOTX` - Serial (via RS-485) Transmit (IN)
`SORX` - Serial (via RS-485) Receive (OUT)

Comment: Why can't the ATtiny do the logical "OR" in its firmware? F5V just becomes a logical input signal, and you only need one opto to drive the MOSFET. Better still, eliminate F5V altogether and send "flash on" and "flash off" as short RS-485 messages broadcast to all nodes.

Comment: Just how tight are your timing requirements?

Comment: The timing signal is essentially the on-off pattern which is a 1Hz PWM signal with a 75% duty cycle. The end result is to keep the indicators appearing to turn on and off at the same time or at worst within a few milliseconds of one another with the same on/off time periods. What I'm kinda also asking with my question is whether or not I'm overthinking about the slight differences in internal clocks on different ICs which would cause a drift by the timing being ever so slightly off.